# List of functions in VSCodde

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have not found any good extension which shows the list of functions in .c file in VSCode? Can you tell?

I have found good results in Eclipse environment in outline

Comment: the c++ extensions can't do that?  I'm surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Install [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools). You can use ctrl+space to force autocompletion.